# What is the biblical basis for the Niceno-Constantinopolitan Creed's claims that the Holy Ghost is the Lord and is to be worshiped and glorified?

Tags: biblical-basis, pneumatology, nicene-creed

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicene_Creed#Niceno-Constantinopolitan_Creed:

> And in **the Holy Ghost**, **the Lord** and Giver of life, who proceedeth from the Father, **who with the Father and the Son together is worshiped and glorified**, who spake by the prophets.

What is the biblical basis for these particular claims in the creed?

Comment: Don't know why this got a downvote, it's a good question that someone learning about the topic should have explained.+1 from me

Comment: All of the elements, except for *Lord*, and *who with the Father and the Son together is worshiped and glorified*, are explicitly found in scripture; the other two are argued from various biblical passages, instead of representing simple quotes; also, the latter was simply a descriptive statement of *de facto* Christian worship, both before and during Arianism, since some Arians argued that *glory to the Father and the Son and the Holy Spirit* is incorrect, and only the formula *glory to the Father through the Son in the Holy Spirit* should be used; both expressions were historically employed.

Comment: I would have thought you would want to refer specifically to the _Athanasian Creed_ in a question which deals with relationships within Deity.

Comment: @NigelJ - I wanted to ask a question about a creed that was closer to the apostolic age. But regarding the Athanasian Creed, somebody already asked this question: [What is the biblical basis for the Athanasian Creed's statement that believing in the Trinity is necessary for salvation?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/49022/50422)

Comment: Note: the creed isn't actually saying that the HG/HS is to *be* worshiped. It is saying that the HG/HS *is* worshiped through worship of the Father and/or Son. (Similarly, worshiping the Son *is* worshiping the Father.)

Comment: @Matthew - good point on the verb *be*, but the word *through* is not found in the text either. The word used is *with*.

Comment: Correct, but I'm arguing that "with" is equivalent to "through/via the worship of", i.e. I was clarifying what is meant by "with". Change the word order: the HG/HS is worshiped (and glorified) *with* [worship and glorification of] the F&S. IOW, the Creed is saying that when the F/S is worshiped and glorified, so also is the HG/HS. So, if one wishes to worship the HG/HS, one can do so "through" / by means of worshiping the Father. (Con't...)

Comment: (...Con't) Which would be a silly desire, because we understand that worshiping one Person is worshiping the Trinity as a whole. One would desire to worship God as a whole, or a specific aspect, in which case, one would worship that Person particularly (while understanding that the whole Trinity is thus worshiped).

Comment: @Matthew - I don't see the *through* interpretation as mandatory. It could very well just mean an statement of a fact, that worship of the HS co-occurs with the worship of the F/S, or that the three were commonly worshiped together.

Comment: In fact, that's *exactly* what I'm arguing. I think you just read in a "must" that I didn't intend. "The HG/HS ___ worshiped and glorified in the worship/glorification of the Father and Son". The blank is "is" (in your words, statement of fact), not "must be" (a mandate).

Comment: @Matthew - the text doesn't say *"in the worship/glorification of the Father and Son"*, the text says *"who with the Father and the Son together is worshiped and glorified"*. In other words, the three are worshiped. How does that happen? We don't know, the text doesn't say, but the *through* reading you suggest is not explicitly found in the text. However, if you are 100% convinced of the *through* interpretation, I invite you to post an answer, justifying your view with references to contemporary early Church sources and biblical support as well (remember this is a `biblical basis` question).