# Are there published testimonies from Unitarians about their experiences with the presence of the Holy Spirit?

Tags: pneumatology, spirituality, unitarianism, testimony

Have any Unitarians experienced the presence of the Holy Spirit, possibly in a dramatic, life-changing way, and published a testimony in which they recount their experiences?

***Note**: this question has been inspired by [this answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/87106/50422).*

EDIT: after some searching I was only able to find [this testimony](https://christadelphianresearch.com/about-myself) which includes experiences with the Holy Spirit *and* Christadelphians (one of the largest Biblical Unitarian denominations). Unfortunately, it turned out to be a testimony from a *former* member, so it doesn't fit the bill. If anyone is able to find a testimony along these lines from an *active* member, that would be fantastic.

Comment: +1 Very interesting question. One thing to remember is that the HS is conceived of differently with Unitarians as opposed to Trinitarians. This page gives a decent overview of some relevant aspects of that. https://restitutio.org/2016/07/26/a-unitarian-view-of-the-holy-spirit/

Comment: In particular, "After consulting both Old and New Testaments, we discovered the holy spirit is a way of talking about God and Jesus in action, especially within the church. Although the spirit is not a person distinct from the Father and Son, it is certainly very personal."

Comment: Similarly, you have Unitarians who talk about the HS as the "gift of God's presence or nature."

Comment: I think it's fine if it's a former Christadelphian, as long as the experiences related to when he was a Christadelphian.

Comment: It's not clear to me from reading that page whether he is a former Christadelphian but a Unitarian, or former for both. Also he doesn't seem to go into much detail regarding it there.